# "[Errno 38] Function not implemented:" occurred when installing Tensorflow Object Detection API on Azure Machine Learning

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection-api, azure-machine-learning-service, tensorflow-model-garden

I tried to install [Object Detection API with Tensorflow 2](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2.md) on Azure Machine Learning with the following commands described in the API Document:

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git

docker build -f research/object_detection/dockerfiles/tf2/Dockerfile -t od .
docker run -it od

cd models/research
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .
python -m pip install --use-feature=2020-resolver .
```

But I got the following error when I execute the last code of the above(`python -m pip install ...`).
The error is too long and each row of the error says `[Errno 38] Function not implemented:`.
The tail of the error is like below:

```
....(omitted)...
('/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/mounts/clusters/(some_path)/models/research/vid2depth/WORKSPACE',
'/tmp/pip-req-build-uxkxrn35/vid2depth/WORKSPACE',
"[Errno 38] Function not implemented: '/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/mounts/clusters/(some_path)/models/research/vid2depth/WORKSPACE'"),
('/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/mounts/clusters/(some_path)/models/research/vid2depth',
'/tmp/pip-req-build-uxkxrn35/vid2depth',
"[Errno 38] Function not implemented: '/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/mounts/clusters/(some_path)/models/research/vid2depth'"),
('/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/mounts/clusters/(some_path)/models/research',
'/tmp/pip-req-build-uxkxrn35',
"[Errno 38] Function not implemented: '/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/mounts/clusters/(some_path)/models/research'")]
```

I have confirmed that the installation of the same commands on my local PC was successful.
Do I need to do anything differently if I want to install it on Azure Machine Learning?